# How To decode Base64 encoded .SVG string using Swift 5.x

Tags: ios, swift, svg, base64, decoding

I want to decode a base64 encoded .svg image using Swift 5.x. Can anybody guide me on how to do it?

I have encoded and decoded base64 .png before. Need help about .svg specifically.

Comment: Why would svg be different to png? What's the problem? Do you have some code that doesn't work on SVG but does on png?

Answer (score 0):

```
  pod 'SVGKit'
```

install this pod and then set up this code is really help me to solve my problem

```
 let temp = qrCode.components(separatedBy: ",")
 let dataDecoded : Data = Data(base64Encoded: temp[1], options:
                         .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!

  let decoded = SVGKImage(data:dataDecoded)
    self.youriimage.image = decoded?.uiImage
```